# MVVMCross Xamarin.Forms.UWP with TipCalc

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, mvvmcross

VS2017 version 15.9.3, Xamarin Forms 3.4, Mvvmcross 6.2.2

In VS2017, it's happy to produce Android, Ios and UWP projects with a common Xamarin forms project.

I'm interested in using MVVMCross to support MVVM and reduce boilerplate code.

The MVVMCross website gives a tutorial on how to make a UWP TipCalc but not a Xamarin.Forms.UWP TipCalc that shares UI code with Android and Ios.

I thought that if I took the UWP Tipcalc project, removed the views and referenced the Forms.UI and Forms.Core project, it would link up properly, but obviously not.

App.xaml

```
<local:TipCalcApp x:Class="MX_TipCalc.UWP.UWP.App"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:local="using:MX_TipCalc.Forms.UWP.UWP"
          RequestedTheme="Light">
    <Application.Resources>
        <x:String x:Key="WelcomeText">Hello World!</x:String>
    </Application.Resources>
</local:TipCalcApp>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Uap.Core;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Uap.Views;

namespace MX_TipCalc.Forms.UWP.UWP
{
    public sealed partial class App
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public abstract class TipCalcApp : MvxApplication<MvxWindowsSetup<Core.App>, Core.App>
    {
    }
}
```

What does it take to get an MVVMCross Xamarin.Forms.UWP project to hook up with the TipCalc.Forms.UI and the TipCalc.Forms.Core to get it working?

## Thanks

So after the answer by Nico Zhu - MSFT
My App.xaml is

```
<local:TipCalcApp x:Class="MX_TipCalc.Forms.UWP.UWP.App"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="using:MX_TipCalc.Forms.UWP.UWP"
                    RequestedTheme="Light">
    <Application.Resources>
        <x:String x:Key="WelcomeText">Hello World!</x:String>
    </Application.Resources>
</local:TipCalcApp>
```

My App.xaml.cs is

```
using MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Uap.Core;
using MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Uap.Views;
using MX_TipCalc.Forms.UI;

namespace MX_TipCalc.Forms.UWP.UWP
{
    public sealed partial class App
    {
        public App()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
       }
    }

    //public abstract class TipCalcApp : 
MvxApplication<MvxWindowsSetup<Core.App>, Core.App>
    //{
    //}

    public abstract class TipCalcApp : MvxWindowsApplication<MvxFormsWindowsSetup<Core.App, FormsApp>, Core.App, FormsApp, MainPage>
    {
    }
}
```

My MainPage.xaml is

```
<mvxf:MvxFormsWindowsPage
   xmlns:mvxf="using:MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Uap.Views"
   x:Class="MX_TipCalc.Forms.UWP.UWP.MainPage"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="using:MX_TipCalc.Forms.UWP.UWP"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d">

   <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

   </Grid>
```

My MainPage.xaml.cs is

```
   using MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Uap.Views;

   namespace MX_TipCalc.Forms.UWP.UWP
   {
       public partial class MainPage : MvxFormsWindowsPage
       {
       public MainPage()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }
       }
   }
```

The good news - it now builds without a problem.

The bad news - it comes up with a System.AccessViolation Exception: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

I put a break point in MX_TipCalc.Forms.UWP.UWP.App.xaml.cs

Public App() InitializeComponent

after that it goes to

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start((p) => new App());
    }
```

then

```
    /// <summary>
    /// GetXamlType(String)
    /// </summary>
    public global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IXamlType GetXamlType(string fullName)
    {
        return _AppProvider.GetXamlType(fullName);
    }
```

After hitting the last curly brace while stepping, it crashes. That's the limit of my knowledge :-(

## Next Step

My latest MainPage.xaml.cs is now

```
namespace MX_TipCalc.Forms.UWP.UWP
{
    public partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

At first, I got messages of missing file "Interop.Manual.cs". I cleaned and rebuilt the solution/projects several times. Eventually, that message did not reappear. I checked that TipCalc.UWP (non Forms version) worked and that TipCalc.Forms.Droid worked. Yep, they still work but when I try the TipCalc.Forms.UWP it still crashes at the same place as before.

Comment: Check the [MvvmCross Playground.Forms.Uwp](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground/Playground.Forms.Uwp) to see how to configure uwp platform with forms

Comment: Thanks. Downloaded Mvvmcross, Cleaned it, had 2 errors, Build it 237 errors. Seems to be missing lots of dll files. Do you know how I can get those restored/downloaded/created? like MvvmCross-develop\MvvmCross.Forms\bin\Debug\uap10.0.16299\MvvmCross.Forms.dll' MvvmCross-develop\MvvmCross.Plugins\JsonLocalization\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\MvvmCross.Plugin.JsonLocalization.dll' How do I force VS2017 to get those from somewhere? Thanks

Comment: I've looked at Playground.Forms.uwp project, in the references it refers to MvvmCross-develop\MvvmCross.Plugins\JsonLocalization\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\MvvmCross.Plugin.JsonLocalization.dll and says Resolved : True ! But when I look at the location, the dll is not there!

Comment: Please remove `: MvxFormsWindowsPage`  parent class from `MainPage`.

Comment: Hi @Alan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: Hi @CoCaIceDew Still unable to get xamarin.forms.uwp to work :(

Answer (score 1):

I have configured uwp platform with forms ui reference this [link](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground/Playground.Forms.Uwp). You could refer the follow steps.

**Add `TipCalc.Forms.UI` reference to `TipCalc.UWP` project.**

[image]

**Replace abstract class `TipCalcApp` with the following code**

```
using MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Uap.Core;
using MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Uap.Views;
using TipCalc.Forms.UI;

namespace TipCalc.UWP
{
    public sealed partial class App
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    //public abstract class TipCalcApp : MvxApplication<MvxWindowsSetup<Core.App>, Core.App>
    //{
    //}
    public abstract class TipCalcApp : MvxWindowsApplication<MvxFormsWindowsSetup<Core.App, FormsApp>, Core.App, FormsApp, MainPage>
    {
    }

}
```

**Modify the `MainPage` xaml as host page.**

```
<mvxf:MvxFormsWindowsPage
    xmlns:mvxf="using:MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Uap.Views"
    x:Class="TipCalc.UWP.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TipCalc.UWP"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    </Grid>

</mvxf:MvxFormsWindowsPage>
```

**At last, remove TipView.xaml file from `TipCalc.UWP` project.** Then it will work.